# times series import from Excel and date manipulation in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have 2 columns of a time series in a .csv excel file, "date" and "widgets"

I import the file into R using:

```
widgets<-read.csv("C:things.csv")
str(things)

'data.frame':   280 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date: Factor w/ 280 levels "2012-09-12","2012-09-13",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ widgets  : int  5 10 15 20 30 35 40 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 95 100 ...
```

How do I convert the factor things$date into either xts or Time Series format?

for instance when I:

```
hist(things)
Error in hist.default(things) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: When you call `read.csv` you might want to `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if you don't want your `character`s be turned into `factor`s. If you want to convert `character` to `Date`, use `?as.Date`; `things$date <- as.Date(as.character(things$date), format = "%Y-%m-%d")` should work here with the `factor` you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading it in as a zoo object and then converting:

```
Lines <- "date,widgets
2012-09-12,5
2012-09-13,10
"
library(zoo)
# replace first argument with:  file="C:things.csv"
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
x <- as.xts(z)
```

Comment: As indicated in the comment it can either be in a character string or a text file.  See `?read.zoo`